# Can't Retrieve Row from mysql database while running java code

Tags: java, mysql, debugging

I have a code which will fetch the row from company table and insert into JComboBox.

When APP runs in **debug mode, the resultset is populated** with data. but when in **normal execution, the result set is empty**!

I am using `Netbeans IDE 7.0.1` for Development and phpmyadmin mysql Database version `5.1.37`.

Below is my code :

```
       boolean isvalue = false; // variable to identify if the company name found or not.
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            st = con.createStatement();
            if(con == null) {
                logger.error("Database Connection Not available.");
                throw new NullPointerException();
            }
            //Set the company name to combo box
            rs = st.executeQuery("Select comp_name from company");
            while (rs.next()) {
                comboCompanyName.addItem(rs.getString("comp_name"));
                isvalue = true; //Set true if found
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("SQLError found while updating information." + ex.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
           System.out.println("Error found while updating information." + ex.getMessage());
        }
        if (!isvalue) //Check company information available
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "System could not found any company information.", "Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
```

Help me out of this.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: any other code after `comboCompanyName.addItem(rs.getString("comp_name"));` for `comboCompanyName` ?

Comment: Your null check is after you access the variable, so you are not going to log anything.

Comment: Where does the message `No data found` come from? I can't find it in your code.

Comment: I've just edited the issue a lil bit... Please have a look see

Comment: any exception in normal mode?

Comment: @nitgeek No. Returned Empty result set :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue.

The Issue because of connection doesn't closed properly. i.e previous connection not closed properly and also i have used static connection object.

Answer (score 0):

Instade of using **isvalue** variable you can try :

```
PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT comp_name FROM company");
  ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
    int i=0;
    while (result.next()) {                         
      jComboBox1.addItem(result.getString(1));
        i++;
       }
     if(i==0){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "System could not found any company information.", "Error",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
   }
```

Comment: @Rajshri When i run this code It always shows **System could not found any company information.** in JOptionPane. Code does't rise any explicit error or exception.